# How to make method call in a class thread-safe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm a java engineer, and I'm trying to find a way to make calling of method in class thread-safe as the code snippet shows below:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.x = X(id)

  def switch(self, new_id):
    self.x = X(new_id) # switch to another object  

  def log(self, msg):
    self.x.log(msg)

a = A()
```

I'm wondering, if `a` is being used by multi-thread, and sometimes `switch` method is called, will `log` method suffer from `NullPointerException` where self.x could be None with chances?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point in the program does `self.x` get set to `None`. If we take a look at the generated Python byte code for the `switch` function, we see that `self.x` is immediately replaced with the new `X` instance without being set to `None`:

```
# Create the new X instance
0  LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (X)
2  LOAD_FAST                1 (new_id)
4  CALL_FUNCTION            1
# Store the new self.x
6  LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
8  STORE_ATTR               1 (x)
# Return from the function
10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
12 RETURN_VALUE
```

To double-check that there won't be any `NullPointerException`-like error such as this:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'log'
```

I created a simple Python script that calls repeatedly the `switch` and `log` methods in two separate threads without acquiring any locks.

```py
import threading
import random

class X:
    def __init__(self, id) -> None:
        self.id = id

    def log(self, msg):
        print(f'{self.id}: {msg}')

class A:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.x = X(id)

  def switch(self, new_id):
    self.x = X(new_id) # switch to another object  

  def log(self, msg):
    self.x.log(msg)

a = A(0)

def switch_t():
    while True:
        a.switch(random.randint(0, 100))

def log_t():
    while True:
        a.log(random.randint(0, 100))

t1 = threading.Thread(target=switch_t)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=log_t)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

I ran this code for two minutes and it never threw any errors.
So, as long as you don't require `self.x` to remain the same during the execution of `log`, in case you wanted to access `self.x` more than one time, your code is completely fine and you won't come across any `NullPointerException`-like error.

One more thing to point out, in `a = A()`, you forgot the constructor arguments.